# Is there a way around log4j.properties at initialization using clj-logging-config?

Tags: logging, clojure

I'm noticing that a lot of libraries my app depends on tend to do some sort of log initialization that doesn't play nicely with clj-logging-config at import time.

For instance: right now, I've got an app with a method that configures logging as follows:

```
(defn set-logging-defaults
  "Set the logging level for the application root"
  []
  (set-loggers! :root {:level :info
                       :out :console
                       :pattern "[%p] %d{MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss} | %m%n"}))
```

This method then gets called in a configuration method before the server starts up, e.g.:

```
(defn -main []
  (init/configure)
  (server/run-server #'app {:port (Integer. (or (System/getenv "PORT") "8080"))
                        :join? false}))
```

However, I have korma.db on the import path for my app's core namespace. The import happens before the logging configuration is executed, and I end up with the following when I launch my app (removing the korma.db import immediately removes this WARN):

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (com.mchange.v2.log.MLog).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

Is there a way around this that I haven't figured out that doesn't rely on either creating a log4j.properties file or executing (set-logging-defaults) at import time? In general, what's the recommended practice here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way around it. I would recommend to use a log4j.properties file.

Answer (score 2):

You could put all the application logic for your server, and associated `:require` directives on problematic third-party libraries, into a separate namespace. Your main namespace would not require this programmatically as part of its `ns` form, but would instead manually load it in the `-main` function and use `eval` to launch the server:

```
(ns myapp.server
  (:require [korma.db :as db] ...))

(defn start-server []
  (server/run-server #'app {:port (Integer. (or (System/getenv "PORT") "8080"))
                            :join? false})
```

Your main namespace then has minimal dependencies, and exists simply to initialize the logging configuration and then invoke the server:

```
(ns myapp.main
  (:require [myapp.init :as init])
  (:gen-class))

(defn -main []
  (init/configure)
  (require 'myapp.server)
  (eval '(myapp.server/start-server)))
```

There are definite drawbacks to this approach. Errors that would normally manifest themselves at load time (such as an unresolved symbol) will now appear at runtime instead. But it should get you around the particular issue that you're seeing.

Having said that, at some point you're probably going to want to go ahead and use logging config files anyways for a project of any decent size. Making code changes to adjust the logging configuration is frequently not a viable option in a production environment, and if the hard-coded logging configuration doesn't capture enough information to diagnose a problem then you're just up a creek.

Comment: What I ultimately ended up using in terms of maximum utility for actually running the application was lein's project.clj `:injections` field - not satisfying for tests and running the repl, but does the trick.

Comment: Returning to this issue a month later, I've accepted that just using a log4j.properties config file is the way to go. I'm not super happy about the fact that I can't work around this otherwise, but having tried everything else out at this point I think it's clear that this is the only reliable method to get the thing to "just work".